# jQuery Plugin getting element ID to use inside AJAX Success

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm building a jQuery plugin.

**Calling the plugin**

```
$('#box').jQueryPlugin({user:'user123'});
```

**JQUERY PLUGIN**

```
(function($){  
    $.fn.jQueryPlugin= function(options) {  

        var  
          defaults = {  
            user: ''
          }

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            var o = options; 

             $.ajax({
               type: "get",
               url: "http://api.domain.com/user/"+o.user,
               data: "",
               dataType: "jsonp",
               success: function(data){
                    var p = data;
                    console.log(p.location);
                    $(this).html(p.location);
               }
            });

          // returns the jQuery object to allow for chainability.  
          return this;  
    }  
})(jQuery);
```

If I were to use the above, the console.log would show an error that it couldn't write the p.location inside the div with id="box"

How would I be able to get it so that it can write to whichever div is specified when calling the plugin?

Comment: `this` doesn't map to any HTML element in your success call. What is `data` supposed to return? What is the objective of your code?

Comment: the code works fine when it has the proper domain etc. my only issue is how to write the value of p.location into the selector used when calling the plugin

Comment: You say `p = data`, what is `data` ? 
As I said, do a `console.log($this)` and see why your `$(this).html` won't map to anything on the DOM. Supposing `data` returns an id of an element, you're doing your selection wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` won't have the context you expect in the `success` callback, so you just need to assign your `div` to a var so you can use it later..

```
(function($){  
    $.fn.jQueryPlugin= function(options) {  

        var  
          defaults = {  
            user: ''
          }

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            var o = options; 

            var $div = $(this);

             $.ajax({
               type: "get",
               url: "http://api.domain.com/user/"+o.user,
               data: "",
               dataType: "jsonp",
               success: function(data){
                    var p = data;
                    console.log(p.location);
                    $div.html(p.location); // now we have the original div;
               }
            });

          // returns the jQuery object to allow for chainability.  
          return this;  
    }  
})(jQuery);
```

Another method would be to set the `context` option in the `$.ajax` call, [see the context option in the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).